# How do you have java create a random number within two ranges (e.g. 5-10 and 12-17)

Tags: java, random, numbers, range

I need to create a random number within two ranges, but I do not know how. Could someone help me?

Comment: rand(1,5) to generate 1->5, then a rand(1) to decide if should be in the 5-10 or 12-17 range...

Comment: Do you mean the union of the two ranges?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

random numbers are generated between 0-1. let's make numbers<0.5 5-10 and numbers > 0.5 12-17 by simply multiplying them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
class PickRandomFromRange
{
    private final List<Integer> range = new ArrayList<>();

    final void addRange(int min, int max)
    {
        for(int i = min; i <= max; i++)
        {
            this.range.add(i);
        }
    }

    int getRandom()
    {
        return this.range.get(new Random().nextInt(this.range.size()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PickRandomFromRange rir = new PickRandomFromRange();
        rir.addRange(5,10);
        rir.addRange(12,17);
        System.out.println(rir.getRandom());
    }
}
```

The above code will basically just makes a list of all the numbers which are in the ranges you give it, then picks a random number from that list, which is therefore a random number from any of the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way, although, I don't know if it is an efficient way of solving my problem.

```
            if(userInput == 4){
            charNumber = 48+random.nextInt(76);
            if(charNumber>47 && charNumber<58){
                outputFile.print((char)charNumber);
                counter++;
            }
            if(charNumber>64 && charNumber<91){
                outputFile.print((char)charNumber);
                counter++;
            }
            if(charNumber>90 && charNumber<97){
                outputFile.print((char)charNumber);
                counter++
            }

            if(charNumber>96 && charNumber<123){
                outputFile.print((char)charNumber);
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ranges 5-10 and 12-17 give you a total of 6 + 6 = 12 possible selections.

Pick a random number from 5 to 16.  If the number is 11 or more then add one to it.  Adding one effectively inserts the gap in your split range.

```
Random myRand = new Random();

// Number in range [5 .. 16].
int num = 5 + myRand.nextInt(17);

// Increase numbers beyond the gap.
if (num >= 11) {
  num += 1;
}
```